# Controlling position for \vline

Tags: tables

I was looking a way to insert vertical line in a table only in some particular case. 
The code and the image below show what I could be able to produce.
 But I do not want that the vertical bars near the numbers. I would like that they were in the expected position: like the one near number 10, should be in the middle between 13 and 10.

I hope I made clear my intention.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }
        \hline
        \vline 9 & 0 & 13 & \vline 10 & 6 & 11 \vline \\
        \hline
        \vline 0 & \vline 15 & 20 & 21 & \vline 22 & 25 \vline \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Resulting table]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way would be not to use vline but rather

```
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{13}
```

to use a `c|` column for that cell.